# Read Write Verilog Reg in NIOS

Tags: nios

How can I read or write verilog reg (variable) in NIOS CPU?
What should I do?
I use DE0 NANO, cyclone IV and NIOS 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  You might want to expand your question with what you have already tried, or at least what documentation you have read.

Comment: You might want to try and ask this question at electronics.SE.

Comment: At first you have to understand the nios2 architecture, driver development, avalon protocol, etc...